# Javascript solve a maze with a moving end position on and X and Y axis (both start and end coordinates are known values)

Tags: javascript, coordinates, maze

Mathematics is not a massive strength of mine. I have a grid with UNKNOWN obstacles on it (shown in black), and the end position of the maze (red) can either be stationary or moving.

I need the start square (yellow) to be able to navigate around the objects and find the red square.

Coordinates for the start square and the end square are always known (meaning yellow does not have to 'find' red, it knows its position and just has to navigate to it, red moves arbitrarily, interdependently of yellow).

I've been working on it for a few days but have come up short.

I managed to get the yellow square to find the red with no obstacles in the way (this was trivial).

I managed to do some really basic collision detection but it was very primitive and only worked in very specific conditions.

[image]

I have looked online at many algorithms. However, all of them seem to know the gird beforehand (e.g., an array matrix).

This code literally just moves the player along the X axis then along the Y. If a 'Collision' is detected, it will just fall through to the next conditional and try to go another way. (As I said, it works in very specific conditions.)

It does not work when objects are thrown into the mix.

I'm not to sure how this is going to help. Doing it this way is totally useless. It needs an actual general purpose algorithm.

I have recently been looking at A* searching algorithm as it is best suited for what I need, but again it seems like you need to pass in a map.

Brief overview:
The socket will send position updates of the monster and the player (X, Y). Both positions are updated.

When a player moves, a command is sent over the web socket.

The web socket then receives a new message stating where the new coordinates are for the entity. (Again this is not really helpful to solving the problem.)

```
ws = new WebSocket('wss://localhost/ws')

var monsters = {}
var currentPlayer = {
    position: {}
};

monstersToLog = [
    'Windsor Rat',
    'Bonecrusher',
    'Windsor Spider',
    'Windsor Bat',
    'Cursed Lich',
    'Forest Oni',
    'Inferno Skeleton',
    'Brown Bear',
    'Kreme',
    'Amon'
]

ws.onmessage = function(event) {
    let data = JSON.parse(event.data)
    entity = data.entityId
    x = data.x
    y = data.y
    orientation = data.o
    dataType = data.$type


    if(dataType.includes('EntitySpawn')){
        if(data.name === 'SteamyRayVaun') {
            currentPlayer.entityId = data.entityId
            console.log("Current Player: ", data);
        }

        if(monstersToLog.includes(data.name)) {
            console.log("Added Bear:", data)
            monsters[data.entityId] = data;
        }
    }

    if(dataType.includes('EntityDestroy')){
        if( monsters[data.entityId]){
            console.log("Removed Monster:", data)
            delete monsters[data.entityId]
        }

    }

    if(dataType.includes('EntityPositionUpdate')){
        if(data.entityId == currentPlayer.entityId) {
            currentPlayer.position.x = data.x;
            currentPlayer.position.y = data.y;
        } else {    
            if(monsters[data.entityId]){
                monsters[data.entityId] = data
            }

        }
    }
};

(function autoHunt (i) {     
    setTimeout(function () { 
        const monsterIDs = Object.keys(monsters)

        if(monsterIDs.length > 0) {
            let currentMonster = monsters[monsterIDs[0]]
            if((currentPlayer.position.x > currentMonster.x) && (diff(currentPlayer.position.x, currentMonster.x) !== 1) && !collisionDetection(currentPlayer.position.x, lastPositionx, currentPlayer.position.y, lastPositiony,'Left')){
                lastPositionx = currentPlayer.position.x
                lastPositiony = currentPlayer.position.y
                console.log('POSITION UPDATe', {lastPositionx, lastPositiony}, 'LEFT')
                move('Left',1)
            } else if ((currentPlayer.position.x < currentMonster.x) && (diff(currentPlayer.position.x, currentMonster.x) !== 1) && !collisionDetection(currentPlayer.position.x, lastPositionx, currentPlayer.position.y, lastPositiony, 'Right')){
                lastPositionx = currentPlayer.position.x
                lastPositiony = currentPlayer.position.y
                console.log('POSITION UPDATe', {lastPositionx, lastPositiony}, 'RIGHT')
                move('Right',1)
            } else if((currentPlayer.position.y > currentMonster.y) && (diff(currentPlayer.position.y, currentMonster.y) !== 1) && !collisionDetection(currentPlayer.position.y, lastPositiony, currentPlayer.position.x, lastPositionx, 'Down')){                 
                lastPositionx = currentPlayer.position.x
                lastPositiony = currentPlayer.position.y
                console.log('POSITION UPDATe', {lastPositionx, lastPositiony}, 'DOWN')
                move('Down',1)
            } else if((currentPlayer.position.y < currentMonster.y) && (diff(currentPlayer.position.y, currentMonster.y) !== 1)&& !collisionDetection(currentPlayer.position.y, lastPositiony, currentPlayer.position.x, lastPositionx, 'Up')){
                lastPositionx = currentPlayer.position.x
                lastPositiony = currentPlayer.position.y
                console.log('POSITION UPDATe', {lastPositionx, lastPositiony}, 'UP')
                move('Up',1)
            }
        }

        autoHunt(true);  
    }, 300)
})(true); 

function move(direction, steps) {
    ws.send(JSON.stringify({"$type":"de.fky.model.PlayerChangeOrientation","orientation":3}));             
    ws.send(JSON.stringify({"$type":`de.fky.model.PlayerMove${direction}`}));
}

function collisionDetection(x, lastx, y, lasty){
    let collision = false
    if((x === lastx) && (y == lasty)){
        collision = true
    }

    if(collision){
        lastPositionx = 0
        lastPositiony = 0
    } 

    return collision
}
```

Comment: what are the API calls you use to move the square?

Comment: Please show your current attempt and explain what it does / doesn't do. Then people have got a starting point to work from.

Comment: @ dGRAMOP - Api calls to get it to move are in the code post above
@ ADyson - code posted above. the code will be of no use to you. this is the first time iv attempted some sort of tracking like this, this is what i got after a couple of hours, before i realised it was way more complex to track things accurately (with obsticals)

Comment: Basically, implement A* pathing algorithm, and run it every few steps to make sure you're still on target, optionally more often as you get closer.

Comment: Let me get this straight, you don't know whether there is an obstacle or not till you hit it?